# Connecting to API using only username, password and clientid

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, api, rest

Hi we have an api we want to connect to, so we can get data out. The organisation has given us the following details to connect.

- Access URL
- Client id
- Username
- Password

Apparently Oauth2 (while used, I am not exactly well known in it), so I have tried to connect various ways, all the time I get a 200 response so a success in connection but the organisation keeps giving me some arbitrary error which doesn't tell me anything. I am thinking I may not have the connections actually set up correctly. So I was wondering with these four pieces of information how would you connect in .net (either vb.net or c#) using visual studio. I must be missing something but like I said I don't know a lot about oauth2. The following is what I have tried.

Version 1

```
var httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(<URL> + string.Format("?grant_type=refresh_token&client_id={0}&username={1}&password={2}", <clientid>, <username>, <password>));
var postData = "";

var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
var data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
httpWReq.Method = "POST";
httpWReq.ContentType = "x-www-form-urlencoded";
httpWReq.ContentLength = data.Length;

using (var stream = httpWReq.GetRequestStream())
{
  stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}

var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();

var result = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Granted this is a POST so I also tried a GET

Version 2

```
var httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(<URL> + string.Format("?grant_type=refresh_token&client_id={0}&username={1}&password={2}", <clientid>, <username>, <password>));

var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
httpWReq.Method = "GET";
httpWReq.ContentType = "x-www-form-urlencoded";
var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();

var result = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Both cases the response is a 200 but I get some message back from the companies api to say not connected due to some authorization issue. That is all it says so I decided to try one more time with

Version 3

```
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(@<URL> + string.Format("?client_id={0}", <clientid>));
req.Method = "GET";
req.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("username:password"));
HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
var result = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Again I get the same thing. the username:password will be the actual usernames and passwords. While anything with a <> so clientid and url are from the information we received. Any help by anyone as to how to connect will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: in OAuth 2 you first need to post you're creencias to the authorize endpoint, this will return you a auth code, then you will need to post this code to the token endpoint that will return you a jet token. You will use this token to authorize all you're queries to the api. For more info: https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/authorization-code-flow

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand, I am not creating this, I am just trying to connect to a third part API. I do not control the oauth2. All I want help is how do I connect to it, what am I missing and how would I code that.